# Is there a way to track the up and down movements of candle sticks in a forex chart with python

Tags: python, automation, bots, browser-automation, webautomation

I am using python to build a trading bot in forex and binary trading websites like pocket option. One problem I can't seem to get over is how to track the movements of candle sticks i.e the values of a currency in real time. I want to be a able to get value or position of candle sticks at say every minute and then store the results in a variable or in a text file.

The reason I can't do this with python is that python seem to rely on being able to reach the web elements on the website, but the section of the website where the candle sticks are is built with one whole canvass and so I cannot reach the elements contained in it.

Can python do this and I just don't know how. If no, is there any other program out there apart from python that I can use to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, just connect to one of websockets to get messages. Investigate in Chrome dev tools which one you need. Then use soft for testing like Selenium or Pyppeteer to click Buy or Sell.

Comment: I have still not been able to get this done. I can connect to Pocket Option websocket quite alright, I able to have access to other parts of the Pocket Option page, except the live chart values. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @donaldekpe if you can connect to websocket, you can parse it and get live candles, as I did in my trading bot: https://github.com/VitalySvyatyuk/pocket_option_trading_bot
Feel free to investigate it and see how I parse candles. For < 1m po_bot.py and for > 1m po_bot_indicators.py